# Fundamental ismorphism theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomial-rings, ring-isomorphism

I don't understand how to apply the fundamental isomorphism theorem to polynomial quotient rings. For example is the ring $\mathbb C[X,Y,Z]/\langle X^2-Z,XZ-Y^3\rangle$ isomorphic to $\mathbb C[X,Y]/\langle X^3-Y^3\rangle$? Can you please elaborate a little? If yes, how is the theorem (the isomorphism theorem) applied here? Thank you!

Comment: The first ring enforces the relation that $X^2-Z=0$, yes? Can you define a map from the first ring to the second using this information?

Comment: I'm thinking at $x \to t, z \to t^2$ but the kernel of this map is $\langle X^2-Z \rangle$.

Comment: Why not try sending $Z\mapsto X^2$ and sending $X\mapsto X$ as well as $Y\mapsto Y$?

Comment: But how is this related to the fundamental theorem of isomorphism?

Comment: The first isomorphism theorem says that for $f:A\to B$ surjective, we have $B\cong A/\ker f$, yes? Do you see how you should fill in the blanks with $A,B,f$? If you complete the mad-lib appropriately, you should get an answer that satisfies you.

Comment: We first need to find the homomorphism between these two spaces. Only after that can we use the theorem. What the comment above is telling you, is the description of a homomorphism between the spaces. Once this is done, you can try to show that this homomorphism is surjective, and injective. Then, the first isomorphism theorem can be used to conclude that the two spaces are isomorphic.

Comment: Let $f$ be the map that sends $Z \to X^2, X \to X, Y \to Y$. $f$ is surjective and $ker(f)=\langle X^2-Z \rangle$ so $\mathbb C[X,Y,Z]/\langle X^2-Z\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C[X,Y]$. How is obtain the isomorphism between the two ring mentioned in the statement?

Comment: The codomain of $f$ should not be just $\mathbb C[X,Y]$, it should be $\mathbb C[X,Y] \over \langle X^3 - Y^3\rangle$. $f$ should then be defined by the map given, composed with the quotient map. This increases the size of the kernel, since the quotient map sends multiples of $X^3 - Y^3$ to zero. So you need to compute the kernel of this map, and show it is generated by $X^2 - Z$ and $XZ - Y^3$ now. Then the first isomorphism theorem works out.

Comment: I'm sorry, what is the quotient map?

Comment: The map that sends every element of $\mathbb C[X,Y]$ to its *equivalence class*  in $\frac{\mathbb C[X,Y]}{\langle X^3 - Y^3\rangle}$. That is  to say, given a polynomial $f(X,Y)$, the image of $f$ under the quotient map is the set $\{f + g(X,Y)(X^2-Y^3) : g(X,Y) \in \mathbb C[X,Y]\}$. More precisely, a representative for $[f]$ is given by the remainder when $f$ is divided by $X^2 - Y^3$, so for example, the image of $X^6 - Y^6$ under the quotient map is zero, because it is a multiple of $X^3 - Y^3$.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. We have two maps. One maps is the map $f$ that sends $Z \to Z^2, X \to X, Y \to Y$, and a map $g$ that sends any polynomial $f(X,Y)$ to its equivalence class in the quotient ring $\mathbb C[X,Y]/ \langle X^3-Y^3 \rangle$. The first map is from $\mathbb C[X,Y,Z]$ to $\mathbb C[X,Y]$ and the second map is from $\mathbb C[X,Y]$ to $\mathbb C[X,Y]/ \langle X^3-Y^3 \rangle$.

Comment: Perfect. Now, you need to figure out the details. Also, if you are still stuck, then I will write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW a slightly different approach: It suffices to show by the UMP of $\mathbb C[x,y,z]/(x^2-z,xz-y^3)$ that there exists a morphism $\xi:\mathbb C[x,y,z]\to \mathbb C[x,y]/(x^3-y^3)$ with the property that for each ring morphism $f:\mathbb C[x,y,z]\to R$ with $f(x^2-z)=f(xz-y^3)=0$ there exists a unique $\tilde{f}:\mathbb C[x,y]/(x^3-y^3)\to R$ satisfying $f=\tilde{f}\circ \xi$.

In particular, let $k$ be the unique map $\mathbb C[x,y,z]\to\mathbb C[x,y]$ that fixes $\mathbb C,x,y$ and maps $z\mapsto x^2$ and let $\eta:\mathbb C[x,y]\to\mathbb C[x,y]/(x^3-y^3)$ be the obvious quotient morphism. We claim that it is sufficient to take $\xi=\eta\circ k$.

To that end, consider some arbitrary $f:\mathbb C[x,y,z]\to R$. By the UMP of polynomial rings, there exists a unique $f':\mathbb C[x,y]\to R$ such that $\forall \zeta\in \mathbb C,\ f'(\zeta)=f(\zeta)$, $f'(x)=f(x)$ and $f'(y)=f(y)$. Furthemore, we have that $\forall p\in \mathbb C[x,y,z],\ f'\circ k(z)-f(z)=f'(x)-f(x)=0$. It follows (again from the UMP of polynomial rings) that $f=f'\circ k$ and furthermore that $f'$ is the unique map with this property.

Now observe that $f'(x^3-y^3)=f'\circ k(x^3-y^3)=f(x)f(x^2-z)+f(xz-y^3)=0$. By the UMP of $\mathbb C[x,y]/(x^3,y^3)$ there exists a unique $\tilde{f}:\mathbb C[x,y]/(x^3-y^3)\to R$ satisfying $f'=\tilde{f}\circ \eta$. It follows that $$f=f'\circ k=(\tilde{f}\circ \eta)\circ k=\tilde{f}\circ (\eta\circ k)$$ And this $\tilde{f}$ can be readily seen as unique. So we're done $\blacksquare$